# Please reopen: 'What is 'major' about the major term in logic?'

Tags: discussion

[What is 'major' about the major term in logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/30929/8572)

I ask because this question involves terms in Logic.

Comment: Just flag the question for reopening, no need to ask on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

One-off purely definitional questions do not really strike me as particularly constructive here (since they are well-covered elsewhere) -- but in the SE spirit, maybe consider a post asking for a glossary or appendix of logical terms, with one definition per answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently (by my count) 3 questions related to this same idea:

1. [Why did Aristotle describe as Extremes: the Major Term and Minor Term?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34766/why-did-aristotle-describe-as-extremes-the-major-term-and-minor-term)
2. [Why did Aristotle choose the terms 'Major Term' and 'Minor Term'?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/why-did-aristotle-choose-the-terms-major-term-and-minor-term)
3. [What is 'major' about the major term in logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30929/what-is-major-about-the-major-term-in-logic)

It seems that we all are having trouble understanding the philosophical problem you're having.